override belongs_to association in subclass
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class ExtraPost < Post
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end

Rails 6.1
When creating an instance of the ExtraPost class, an error occurs that the user cannot be absent. Please tell me if this way of overriding the association is not supported in Rails.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a specific answer on the internet.

You solution looks ok and seems to be working on my Rails 6 project.
Don't you have constraint on database level for posts.user_id? Could you please provide full backtrace error + values of ExtraPost._reflections['user'] vs. Post._reflections['user'].

I think the issue here is that what the optional: option does is call validates_presence_of :user in the User class. Redefining the association in the subclass does not remove this validation and should not really be expected to. The easiest solution would be to set belongs_to :user, optional: true in the User class and add the validation with validates_presence_of :user, if: :user_required? . user_required? being a method you would define and override in the subclass.

@peresvetjke - I can verify that the issue exists in Rails 7.0.4 and it most likely exists ever since they added the validation to the belongs_to macro.

@max think you are right. Interesting. Here is the issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32953, still not solved I guess.

@peresvetjke I'm not suprised. Rails 7 still doesn't even have an official way of skipping/removing validations defined in a superclass. You have to poke into the internal implemention details of ActiveModel::Validations and it involves way to many things starting with an underscore to be comfortable.

The issue here is that the belongs_to association macro adds a validation by default and redefining the association in the child class does not remove the validation.
Instead you can just define the validation manually and add a if: condition that you can override in subclasses.
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  validates_presence_of :user, if: :user_required?

  private

  def user_required?
    true
  end
end

class ExtraPost < Post
  def user_required?
    false
  end
end


In your Post model, set up your belongs_to like this:
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee, optional: true
  validates_presence_of :employee, if: Proc.new { self.instance_of?(self.class.base_class) }
  ...

And then remove the belongs_to in the ExtraPost model.  (It automatically inherits the one from the parent class.)
In this way, any subclass of Post, such as ExtraPost, can be saved without requiring a related employee.

That's one way to do it but it does make the assumption that the validation should be skipped for all subclasses.
